# how to change object attribute values with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, visual-studio-code, backend

ok so I have this array with objects, I want to make a function with 2 parameters so I can change one or more of their attributes values

```
let list = [{name: "kyle" , surname: "smith" , age: 24,id= 0}, {name: "leyla" , surname: "simpson" , age: 21,id =1},{name: "sean" , surname: "rogers" , age: 27, id=2}]

function updateProductById(id, x){
what can I do here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your object intitializer is incorrect. You need to use `:` instead of `=`. Then to update the property you will need at least three parameters: the ID, the property to update and the value to update to.

#### Mutable approach

Then in the function you need to [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the element having the ID and then simple update the property. If the property does not yet exist, it is not added (one could easily change this behavior).

```js
let list = [{
  name: "kyle",
  surname: "smith",
  age: 24,
  id: 0
}, {
  name: "leyla",
  surname: "simpson",
  age: 21,
  id: 1
}, {
  name: "sean",
  surname: "rogers",
  age: 27,
  id: 2
}]

function updateById(id, propName, value){
  let itemToUpdate = list.find(x => x.id === id);
  if (itemToUpdate !== undefined) {
    itemToUpdate[propName] = value;
  }
}

console.log(list[0])
updateById(0, "name", "Thomas");
console.log(list[0])
```

#### Immutable approach

The above approach mutates the original list. If you want to treat objects as [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) you could use the following approach which utilizes the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a new array with an updated value.

```js
let list = [{
  name: "kyle",
  surname: "smith",
  age: 24,
  id: 0
}, {
  name: "leyla",
  surname: "simpson",
  age: 21,
  id: 1
}, {
  name: "sean",
  surname: "rogers",
  age: 27,
  id: 2
}]

function updateByIdImmutable(lst, id, propName, value) {
  const index = lst.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
  if (index !== -1) {
    const updatedItem = { ...lst[index],
      [propName]: value
    };
    return Object.assign([...lst], {
      [index]: updatedItem
    });
  }
  return lst;
}

console.log(list[0])
const updatedList = updateByIdImmutable(list, 0, "name", "Thomas");
console.log(updatedList[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 3 parameters.  The ID to search for, the name of the property to update, and the value to set the property to.

```js
let list = [{name: "kyle" , surname: "smith" , age: 24,id:0}, {name: "leyla" , surname: "simpson" , age: 21,id:1},{name: "sean" , surname: "rogers" , age: 27, id:2}]

function updateProductById(id, propName, value){
  list.find(item => item.id === id)[propName] = value;
}

updateProductById(0, "name", "steve");

console.log(list);
```